# How to check if property bound from inside custom control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

I have custom control which have `OperationMode` and depending on this property I need to do certain things.

I also have other dependency properties like `Property1` and `Property2`. I need to make sure that when user uses control in one way (certain OperationMode) then control doesn't have any bindings to `Property1`

So, I wonder if there any way to programmaticaly check to make sure that property have or don't have bindings associated with specific dependency property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the control's `GetBindingExpression` to test if a binding has been applied to a dependency property:-

```
 bool property1IsBound = GetBindingExpression(Property1Property) != null;
```